# Remove TIME from DATE in a textbox c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Datagridview and when i click a button i want to populate my textboxes and one of which is a textbox that contains only the date. The data will be retrieve from a mysql database and the data type is date time. There is always 12:00 When I retrieve a data. I have a cell content click event

Here is my code:

```
Txtreqshipdate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[9].Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Error message:

> The string was not valid datetime. There is a unknown word starting at
>   index 0

Answer (score 4):

Use [**DateTime.ParseExact()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
DateTime back =DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd",row.Cells[9].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Txtreqshipdate.Text = back;
```

Comment: There is no CultureInfo but there is CultureInfoConverter.

Comment: @Philip what do you mean?

Comment: When i try to type CultureInfo the only thing that display is CultureInfoConverter

Comment: make sure you added this using System.Globalization;

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to handling this in C#, you could also use MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT` to convert the `datetime` into a string formatted as you want:

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%M/%d/%Y')
```

Then your code would presumably simplify to:

```
Txtreqshipdate.Text = row.Cells[9].Value;
```

This approach might be preferable to handling the conversion in C# because it frees the app layer from worrying about database column types.

Comment: How exactly I can use DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: @Philip However the value was being selected in your query, just use `DATE_FORMAT` as I have above _before_ bringing it into C#.  Then it will already be a string and you shouldn't have to deal with the conversion problem.

Comment: You can format it with C# or MySQL. The above formats the DateTime in the query directly. Or even you can format in C# given by @Sajeetharan.

Comment: Please mark correct if it solved your problem, thanks.